# Python package both as application and as lib

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am aware there already is a question like this however I am working on this for over an hour now and I can't get it to work at all.

I have a package that has unit tests using nosetests, and certain classes are importable. I have the following structure:

```
setup.py
/RecurrenceRelationSolver
-- __init__.py
-- RecurrenceRelation.py
-- RecurrenceRelationParser.py
-- RecurrenceRelationSolver.py
/tests
-- __init__.py
-- context.py
-- test_homogenous.py
```

The github is here: https://github.com/rowanG077/RecurrenceRelationSolver

My `__init__.py` looks like this since I want to allow other people to import these classes:

```
from .RecurrenceRelation import RecurrenceRelation
from .RecurrenceRelationParser import RecurrenceRelationParser
```

In my case the `RecurrenceRelationSolver.py` does not contain any classes but something like this:

```
from . import RecurrenceRelationParser
from . import RecurrenceRelation

def main():
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then in my unit tests `__init__.py` is empty and in `context.py` I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from RecurrenceRelationSolver import RecurrenceRelation, RecurrenceRelationParser
```

The way it is structured right now I can run the unit tests succesfully however when I am in the `RecurrenceRelationSolver` directory and run `python RecurrenceRelationSolver.py` it does not work with the following message:

```
from . import RecurrenceRelationParser
ImportError: cannot import name 'RecurrenceRelationParser'
```

I'm not sure how to do this since I never made a module like this. Is there anyway I can structure my imports that I can keep using the package as a library and as directly runnable?

Any help is appreciated!

I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. The problem is you are trying to run the code in wrong way.

You should not have to modify `sys.path` in order to run your tests (or in general any `sys.path.insert(...)` is a code smell. In 99% of the cases there are better alternatives).

You should launch your tests from **outside** the `tests` folder, so that the package is available. If you use tools like `py.test` or `nosetests` you can tell them where the source code is and *they* will take care to modify the `PYTHONPATH` accordingly.

Second: it's simply wrong to go into a package directory and do anything. Packages are units, you should never need to go inside them to do something.

To run your script properly run it from outside the package using the `-m` switch:

```
python3 -m RecurrenceRelationSolver.RecurrenceRelationSolver
```

Alternatively you can write a script, *outside* your package, that imports that module and runs the main function. If you are using `setuptools` in your `setup.py` you can [use the `entry_points` parameter to define some `console_scripts` automatically.](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation)